# website extensions removing non `.htm` links

Tags: r

I am trying to remove some links in R. I have data which looks like the following:

```
 [1] "mcd-9302018x10q.htm   iXBRL" "mcd-6302018x10q.htm   iXBRL"
 [3] "mcd-3312018x10q.htm   iXBRL" "hog-09302018x10q.htm"       
 [5] "hog-07012018x10q.htm"        "hog-04012018x10q.htm"       
 [7] "hog-09242017x10q.htm"        "hog-06252017x10q.htm"       
 [9] "arcb-20180930x10q.htm"       "arcb-20180630x10q.htm"      
[11] "arcb-20180331x10q.htm"       "arcb-20170930x10q.htm"      
[13] "gniop143713_10q.htm"         "gniop142571_10q.htm"        
[15] "gniop141357_10q.htm"         "gniop134249_10q.htm"        
[17] "gniop132661_10q.htm"         "gniop131047_10q.htm"        
[19] "gniop123863_10q.htm"         "gniop122144_10q.htm"        
[21] "gniop121262_10q.htm"         "gniop114805_10q.htm"        
[23] "gniop113353_10q.htm"         "gniop112046_10q.htm"        
[25] "gniop105149_10q.htm"         "gniop103435_10q.htm"        
[27] "gniop101832_10q.htm"         "gniop094765_10q.htm"        
[29] "gniop093202_10q.htm"         "slt_10q.txt"                
[31] "slti-10q_53808.txt"          "sl-10q_53416.txt"           
[33] "sl-10q_52573.txt"            "surgical10q_52119.txt"      
[35] "slt-10q_51671.txt"           "0001.txt"                   
[37] "0001.txt"                    ""
```

I am not interested in Reading `.txt` and  `""` links only the `.htm` links. However using `grepl` to extract the HTML links still leaves me with `"mcd-9302018x10q.htm   iXBRL"` - which I do not want since `iXBRL`  Will break the link.

How can I go about extracting just the links here with `.htm` as the extension?

Data:

```
links <- c("mcd-9302018x10q.htm   iXBRL", "mcd-6302018x10q.htm   iXBRL", 
"mcd-3312018x10q.htm   iXBRL", "hog-09302018x10q.htm", "hog-07012018x10q.htm", 
"hog-04012018x10q.htm", "hog-09242017x10q.htm", "hog-06252017x10q.htm", 
"arcb-20180930x10q.htm", "arcb-20180630x10q.htm", "arcb-20180331x10q.htm", 
"arcb-20170930x10q.htm", "gniop143713_10q.htm", "gniop142571_10q.htm", 
"gniop141357_10q.htm", "gniop134249_10q.htm", "gniop132661_10q.htm", 
"gniop131047_10q.htm", "gniop123863_10q.htm", "gniop122144_10q.htm", 
"gniop121262_10q.htm", "gniop114805_10q.htm", "gniop113353_10q.htm", 
"gniop112046_10q.htm", "gniop105149_10q.htm", "gniop103435_10q.htm", 
"gniop101832_10q.htm", "gniop094765_10q.htm", "gniop093202_10q.htm", 
"slt_10q.txt", "slti-10q_53808.txt", "sl-10q_53416.txt", "sl-10q_52573.txt", 
"surgical10q_52119.txt", "slt-10q_51671.txt", "0001.txt", "0001.txt", 
"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *regular expression* you can get the links that end in `.htm`:

```
grep(pattern = ".htm$", x = links, value = T)

[1] "hog-09302018x10q.htm"  "hog-07012018x10q.htm"  "hog-04012018x10q.htm"  "hog-09242017x10q.htm"  "hog-06252017x10q.htm"  "arcb-20180930x10q.htm" "arcb-20180630x10q.htm"
 [8] "arcb-20180331x10q.htm" "arcb-20170930x10q.htm" "gniop143713_10q.htm"   "gniop142571_10q.htm"   "gniop141357_10q.htm"   "gniop134249_10q.htm"   "gniop132661_10q.htm"  
[15] "gniop131047_10q.htm"   "gniop123863_10q.htm"   "gniop122144_10q.htm"   "gniop121262_10q.htm"   "gniop114805_10q.htm"   "gniop113353_10q.htm"   "gniop112046_10q.htm"  
[22] "gniop105149_10q.htm"   "gniop103435_10q.htm"   "gniop101832_10q.htm"   "gniop094765_10q.htm"   "gniop093202_10q.htm"
```